# Why in linux kernel sound driver code is placed separately in /sound rather than /driver

Tags: linux-kernel, driver

I am recently skimming linux kernel code and find that sound driver code is placed in /sound while other drivers for example gpu is in /driver. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3):

For historical reasons.

Once upon a time, the kernel took the [OSS](http://www.opensound.com/oss.html) sound drivers and put them into `/drivers/sound/`. However, the OSS author later stopped developing the free drivers and tried to sell his own as an add-on, so the drivers in the kernel were not really well maintained. For this reason, almost every distribution added the [ALSA](https://www.alsa-project.org/) drivers to the kernel instead. The ALSA patch used `/sound` to avoid conflicts with the OSS drivers.

Beginning with the 2.6 kernel series, the ALSA drivers were officially merged into the kernel, and still put under `/sound` as a makeshift arrangement because the OSS drivers were kept for compatibility reasons.

Nowadays, the OSS drivers are gone, but moving the sound drivers into `/drivers` would cost time and effort, without much of a benefit, so nobody wants to bother doing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.